# keras.utils.Sequence with multiple files

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I understand how to use `keras.utils.Sequence` with one data file. You subclass the `keras.utils.Sequence` class and implement its interface: `__len__` and `__getitem__`.

For example:

```
def __len__(self):
    "Denotes the number of batches per epoch"
    return int(np.ceil(self.no_examples / float(self.batch_size)))

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    #build the batch w/ idx and self.batch_size
```

But what if your data is spread across multiple files? For example:

- train_part1.csv
- train_part2.csv
- train_partn.csv

How can you iterate through all batches with only one pointer `idx`?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 2):

you can set up a mapping of (range, file_path)

```py
def __init__(self, file_paths, batch_size):
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self._mapping = dict()
    count = 0
    for file_path in file_paths:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            size = len(f.readlines())
            self._mapping[(count, count+size)] = file_path
        count += size
    self.no_examples = count

def _find_file_path(self, idx):
    for range, file_path in self._mapping.items():
        start, end = range[0], range[1]
        if start <= idx and idx <= end:
            in_file_idx = idx - start
            return (in_file_idx, file_path)

def __len__(self):
    "Denotes the number of batches per epoch"
    return int(np.ceil(self.no_examples / float(self.batch_size)))

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=128)  # add memoize for file caching
def _read_file_data(self, file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        return list(f.readlines())

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    in_file_idx, file_path = self._find_file_path(idx)
    lines = self._read_file_data(file_path)
    return lines[in_file_idx]
```

Further optimization:

- stats memory consumed, delete memoized file content(if your files are too large to fit your memory) due to your memory size;
- implement more efficient _find_file_path if large number of files, the current implementation is O(n);